# How can i make my advertisement be displayed on the home screen of my phone?

Tags: codenameone

The advertisement place I need to put is inside of home screen.
what I need is:

**I need to people to see my advertisement when the phone is not doing anything...**

***such as home screen....***

when you click the home button after phone lock, it goes to home screen...
that is the place I want to insert my advertisement
Is this possible to do in codenameone?

I am now using the nativeInterface method to do what i want, but here is the error i got when trying to compile

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.faugan.addscreen.MyNativeContentImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1001)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:100)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:50)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.codename1.system.NativeLookup.create(NativeLookup.java:81)
    at com.faugan.addscreen.MyApplication.lambda$start$0(MyApplication.java:47)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3260)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2651)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3239)
Rendering frame took too long 722 milliseconds
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2025)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1070)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:999)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.faugan.addscreen.MyApplication.lambda$start$0(MyApplication.java:48)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3260)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2651)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3239)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2025)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1070)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:999)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Rendering frame took too long 154 milliseconds
```

I also read that native code can not be executed in the simulator, is it why i am having thise error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with Codename One, neither is it possible on any other platform.

You may simulate this by developing an app that changes the screensaver, but this will only work on Android and not on iOS because Apple will not allow such app. In fact, iPhones and iPads don't have Screensaver, just Wallpaper.

Comment: FYI even on Android where this is technically possible it is very likely your developer account will be banned for ToS violations if you do that... StartApp did something far more tame and apps that included that got banned.

Comment: Thanks Diamond and Shai for your intervention, but Diamond how can i changes the screensaver with codenameone? can you give some tip for that?

Comment: Codename One can't do that out-of-the-box, you will have to do it through a native interface. https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-interface.html or https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: Kindly ask this as a new question. Say what you're trying to do, what you've done and what you're getting.

Comment: Thanks it is done i just post a new question for this matter